# is there any alternative for this SELECT * FROM type WHERE tid='1' OR tid='2'; query?

Tags: mysql

is there any alternatives for this MySQL query?

```
SELECT * FROM type WHERE tid='1' OR tid='2';
```

here type is the table and tid is the id of the table and i want to select first 2 rows any way

totally there are 3 rows

the above query is working but at certain times server displays nothing ,everyone suggests it is because the server is getting confused due to the query given

any alternatives please....

Comment: Not everyone suggests "it is because the server is getting confused". Leave my name off that list of everyone. Certainly, there are alternatives that will return an equivalent result. But the server isn't going to be "confused" by your query.

Comment: sometimes the server displays nothing when the same query is executed to bring the selected rows to a select box.

Comment: sorry i am just a beginer and i am learning.pardon me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the IDs are not guaranteed to be gapless. They most likely aren't.

What you need is the keyword `LIMIT`.
Just as Garr Godfrey already answered, you sort the table by the id (ascending by default) and then limit the results to 2 at maximum

```
SELECT tid, foo, bar FROM type ORDER BY tid LIMIT 2
```

You should have a look at the basic SQL keywords. They already do most of the stuff you usually need

Comment: thanks @felk works fine can you also suggest me how to select the last 2 rows from the same table

Comment: you would add a `DESC` (for descending, `ASC`/ascending is default) into the query: `... ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 2`

Comment: am sory i am not able to vote up because i am not having 15 reputation

Comment: no problem, that was really basic SQL. For your next question, crawling a bit through the manual might bring you an answer even earlier :)

Comment: i know even i tried many queries earlier ,but i want an efficient query

Comment: and i think your query is that one

Answer (score 1):

maybe if those IDs don't exist you'd have problem, but there is nothing confusing about that query. Try

```
SELECT * FROM `type` ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2
```

that will select the lowest 2 ids

Comment: thanks @garr godfrey can you also suggest me how to select the last 2 rows from the same table

Comment: in one query you probably can't get both, but you add DESC after your ORDER BY list to get the highest IDs